# How to add georeferenced TIFF to AutoCAD 2010

Tags: geotiff-tiff, georeferencing, autocad

I have a ~6GB georeferenced (from ArcGIS) .TIFF satellite image that a colleague wishes to add to AutoCAD 2010. He wants it as a base layer for digitising features from. I have searched forums but everyone seems to be talking about AutoCAD Map 3D when discussing adding a georeferenced .TIFF. I have used the 'add World File' tool for the .TIFF. It seems that the normal route of adding a layer attachment does not work. Does anyone know if it is even possible for AutoCAD 2010 to understand a georeferenced .TIFF created in ArcGIS?

Originally it was a raster catalog which I exported to a .TIFF. I would ultimately like to make a WMS for this, but don't have the requried ArcGIS extensions.

Comment: AutoCAD Map 3D required - workaround is for AutoCAD 2010 AutoCAD Raster Design 2009 Object Enabler http://docs.autodesk.com/MAP/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%20Map%203D%202010%20User%20Documentation/HTML%20Help/index.html?url=WS1a9193826455f5ff5cf1d02511b1d000978-2cac.htm,topicNumber=d0e185294

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible for autocad (base) to understand georeferencing information in the tiff.
If a colleague were to load the image for you with a projection and the georeferenced image into a drawing (using autocad map 3d), that drawing can be opened and used in autocad.

Comment: Ok, so we just need to find someone in the organisation with AutoCAD Map 3d to initiate a file with this image in it and it can be used thereafter with AutoCAD 2010... ? That might be a nice workaround.

Comment: you will want to make sure the map dwg is saved as 2010 and the coord sys is set to the one you want to digitize in. otherwise your map user will have to re-project it for you. If you want the data back out to shape file you will have to use map again anyway.

Comment: As mapperz mentioned the object enabler will provide some funtionality. however it still won't help with projection for digitizing. I would also start by verifying the coordinates of a point on the ground to make sure you don't have any shift or incorrect prj reading between esri and autodesk. i.e. the projection of the tiff is read as inches or meters.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly address adding your image from a local source, but take a look at this free tool from ESRI to work with web services in AutoCAD. With this tool you can use many web services in AutoCAD directly--including imagery base maps. 
http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgis-for-autocad

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately we don't have ArcServer.

Answer (score 1):

Use BricsCAD, which is in fact an affordable copy of AutoCAD.
This software is able to read the geocoded information of a geotiff.